# проблема с кнопкой назад в тулбаре

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть 3 фрагмента они переключаются через шторку которая выдвигается слева или тремя полосками сверху слева(в тулбаре) с них можно перейти на 4 фрагмент на нем место трех полосной кнопки появляется стрелка и она превращается в кнопку назад и мне надо ее заставить помимо ее работы еще и сохранять данные как мне это сделать из фрагмента пытался так

```
var toolb = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
toolb.setNavigationOnClickListener {
    back()
}
```

но это вызвало ошибку

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Toolbar.setHasTransientState(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

код экрана

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.001">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

код фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/editlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApplication.FullscreenContainer"
    tools:context=".Edit">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameplaintext"
            android:layout_width="373dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Заголовок"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Button"
            app:icon="@drawable/free_icon_microphone_3364184"
            app:iconGravity="top"
            app:iconSize="43dp"
            app:iconTint="#000000"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlistlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CheckBox" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="113dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/noteplaintext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="Заметка"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А что метод back() делает. И на какой конкретно строке и в каком классе падает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [кнопка назад в тулбаре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1500175/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: он сохраняет нужные данные в бд котлиновский код прописан в файле фрагмента

Comment: больше не дубликат